# Algorithm for sorting within windows

Tags: algorithms, sorting, algorithm-design

I am writing an app which displays speeches on various topics, with each speech having a number of attributes. I want to give the user the choice to sort a list of speeches by an attribute, even within a previously sorted list of speeches.

**Consider for example**: Suppose the previous list had been sorted by the attribute: *"speaker's name"*, and there were three different speakers (so the list was split into three windows with each window consisting of the same *speaker*). Now, the user wants to sort the speeches based on the attribute: *"length of the speech"* such that the new list would now be sorted by *speaker's name*, and within each window of the *speaker's name*, the speeches would be sorted by the *length* (creating a new window within this window for each length of speech in the speaker's window).

I would like to give the user the ability to do this with an arbitrary number of attributes. How can I go about doing such sorting, preferably in the most efficient way?

P.S: I am just a teenage programmer who has been programming for a few years and can understand algorithms in concrete steps - I have not taken college classes in CS, so please keep that in mind when explaining the algorithms.

Comment: Just want to clarify, say your 3 speeches represented with attributes $a, b, c$ so you have
$s_1 = (a_1,b_1,c_1), s_2 = (a_2,b_2,c_2), s_3 = (a_3,b_3,c_3)$  And say you sort them first using the $b$ attribute then $a$? If this is the case, are you familiar with [stable sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you require is the **lexicographic** ordering. Let me describe this.

Suppose the speeches have two attributes. The first one is "*speaker's name*" and the second one is the "*length*". For simplification, let me define the *speaker's name* by the integer value instead of a character string. Now, suppose the speeches are represented using the following tuples: $(0,0)$, $(1,2)$, $(0,3)$, $(1,4)$, $(2,3)$, $(2,4)$, and $(1,1)$. Here, the second speech has the speaker's name: $1$, and length $= 2$.

**Requirement 1:** You simply want to sort the speeches by the "*speaker's name*".

Just consider the first attribute for comparing any two speeches and apply any sorting algorithm. You will get the following ordering: $(0,0)$, $(0,3)$, $(1,2)$, $(1,4)$, $(1,1)$, $(2,3)$, and $(2,4)$.

**Requirement 2:** You want to sort first by the "*speaker's name*" and then by the "*length*". This is the requirement that you have mentioned in your question.

Now, define a *new* comparison operation between two tuples as follows: $(a,b) < (c,d)$ if and only if $(a<c)$ or $(a = c$ and $b<d)$
Here, we are comparing by giving the "first attribute" more priority. And if the first attribute value is the same, we compare based on the "second attribute".

Smilarly, you can define $(a,b) > (c,d)$ if and only if ($a>c$) or ($a = c$ and $b>d$).

Now, you can simply use any sorting algorithm by replacing the standard comparison operation with the above-defined comparison operation.

You will get the following ordering: $(0,0)$, $(0,3)$, $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(1,4)$,  $(2,3)$, and $(2,4)$.

**Requirement 3:** Suppose, you want to sort by the *length* and then by the *speaker's name*

Simply, define the comparison operation between two tuples as: $(a,b) < (c,d)$ if and only if $(b<d)$ or $(b = d$ and $a<c)$. Now, again you can use any standard sorting algorithm by replacing the standard comparison operation with this comparison operation.

You will get the following ordering: $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(0,3)$, $(2,3)$, $(1,4)$,  and $(2,4)$.

---

Similarly, you can define a new comparison operation for the multiple attributes based on your requirements.